# Removing duplicates from a bag returned by xsl:key based on attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, duplicates

I have the following xml file.

```xml
<Bank>
  <Person personId="1" type="1071" deleted="0">
  </Person>
  <Person personId="2" type="1071" deleted="0">
  </Person>
  <Person personId="3" type="1071" deleted="0">
  </Person>
  <Account>
    <Role personId="1" type="1025" />
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Role personId="1" type="1025" />
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Role personId="1" type="1018" />
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Role personId="3" type="1025" />
    <Role personId="1" type="1018" />
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Role personId="2" type="1025" />
  </Account>
</Bank>
```

and the following xsl transformation.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="roleKey"
    match="Role[(@type = '1025' or @type = '1018' or @type = '1022' or @type = '1023') and not(@validTo)]"
    use="@personId" />

  <xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@personId" />
    <xsl:variable name="roles" select="key('roleKey', @personId)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$roles">
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@type" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The actual result is following and I would like to remove the duplicated `type` values.

```xml
1;1025;1025;1018;1018
2;1025
3;1025
```

The expected results should be like follows...

```xml
1;1025;1018
2;1025
3;1025
```

I have tried the tips involving keyword `following` from [this website](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2696.html) and also the trick with the Muenchian method. They all do not work as they seem to be browsing through the whole document and matching the duplicates for each and every `Person` element, whereas I want to remove duplicates only in a `Person` context defined by `personId` attribute.

How do I remove those duplicates from the bag returned by `key` function? Or maybe there is a method that I can use in `xsl:for-each` to print only what I want to?

I can only use what there is available in XSLT 1.0. I do not have a possibility to use any XSLT 2.0 processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, do not know if this is the best solution available but I achieved what I wanted by introducing such a key and using Muenchian method.

```
<xsl:key name="typeKey" match="Role" use="concat(@type, '|', @personId)" />
```

The whole transformation looks like that after the change...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="roleKey"
    match="Role[(@type = '1025' or @type = '1018' or @type = '1022' or @type = '1023') and not(@validTo)]"
    use="@personId" />
  <xsl:key name="typeKey" match="Role" use="concat(@type, '|', @personId)" />

  <xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@personId" />
    <xsl:variable name="roles" select="key('roleKey', @personId)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$roles[generate-id() = generate-id(key('typeKey', concat(@type, '|', @personId)))]">
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@type" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the actual result is now...

```
1;1025;1018
2;1025
3;1025
```